# Insert a row in a table in Titanium

Tags: mysql, database, titanium

I have used the insert query on a table when the table is empty, it executes perfect and insert the data, when I use the same insert query with same values then it pops up with the error

and I get an error

```
var insert_query=  Alloy.Globals.database_file.execute('INSERT INTO get_appointments (appointment_number,end_date_time,location,start_date_time) VALUES (?,?,?,?)', app_number, app_end_time,app_loc, app_start_time);


[ERROR] :  Script Error {
[ERROR] :      backtrace = "#0 () at :0";
[ERROR] :      line = 127;
[ERROR] :      message = "Error occurred calling next on a PLSqliteResultSet. SQLite error: 'column appointment_number is not unique' for 'INSERT INTO get_appointments (appointment_number,end_date_time,location,start_date_time) VALUES (?,?,?,?)'";
[ERROR] :      sourceId = 299620896;
[ERROR] :      sourceURL = "file:///Users/obaid_infrability/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1/Applications/F58D6E16-22D1-4C45-A800-7DE57DA00DDA/Qima%20App.app/app.js";
[ERROR] :  }
```

The reason for this error is the **appointment_number is set to unique** but I don't understand why it pops up the error it should just skip if the value already exists.

What I have to do to skip the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options to handle this, and you should choose the best solution for your application

1. If you want to ignore those errors - catch this error in your code, and ignore it.
2. If you want to update the all row information with new values - you can instead on "INSERT INTO" - use "REPLACE INTO".
3. If you want to update several fields only from the request - you can use "INSERT INTO ..... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE .... "

Comment: Your solution seems interesting but can you tell me more about "catch this error in your code, and ignore it." how to do this?

Comment: I have used try{
              var insert_query=  Alloy.Globals.database_file.execute('INSERT INTO get_appointments (appointment_number,end_date_time,location,start_date_time) VALUES (?,?,?,?)', app_number, app_end_time,app_loc, app_start_time);
            }
        catch (e){
            var message=e.message;
            console.log('error = '+ message);
        }

Comment: @obaid try-catch is a good option and i think you did it correctly, but a small comment **beware of `console.log` use `Ti.API.info` instead**.

Comment: can i know the harm of using console.log? just for info

Comment: @obaid I'm not familiar with the programming language that your are using, but you do it with "try-catch" operation. It has different syntax in different languages. in some it called try - except . so just find the proper syntax for your language.

Comment: Its perfect and correct what I have used here and its Titanium Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the column to **Unique** it won't keep if the value already exists. Since, its similar to **primary key**. The only difference between ***unique*** and ***primary key*** is that primary key can be set to only one column in a table whereas unique can be set to more than one column in a table.

*Remove the unique constraint for the column if you wanna add the value even if it already exists.*

Comment: My aim is to not to add the same value again if it exists.